# How to unzip a dump file created by Rethinkdb

Tags: bash, rethinkdb

In a Linux directory `~/Documents/Scratch`, I've created the following tar file using the `rethinkdb dump` command:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Documents/Scratch$ ls -tr | tail -n1
rethinkdb_dump_2016-10-10T16:58:32.tar.gz
```

However, if I try to untar this file, I get an "unexpected end of file" error:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Documents/Scratch$ tar -zxvf rethinkdb_dump_2016-10-10T16:58:32.tar.gz
tar (child): Cannot connect to rethinkdb_dump_2016-10-10T16: resolve failed

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 128
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Do I perhaps have to rename the file before unzipping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can rename it.

```
mv rethinkdb_dump_2016-10-10T16\:58\:32.tar.gz  rethinkdb.tgz
tar zxvf rethinkdb.tgz
```

Or you can force it to look localy using --force-local:

```
tar -zxvf rethinkdb_dump_2016-10-10T16\:58\:32.tar.gz --force-local
```